# css background image is not loading in list

Tags: css, background-image

I'm trying to load a background image with a "before" tag into a list to create a checkmark image at the back of the list, but the images aren't showing up. What is the problem? Here is the code:

```css
.list1 li:before {
  content: '';
  background: url('../img/Без\ названия.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">



    <title>Document</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="stylize">
        стилизируй с помощью псевдоклассов и псевдоэлементов
      </div>
      <div class="mainlist">
        <ul class="list1">
          <li>Put on this page information about your product</li>
          <li>A detailed description of your product</li>
          <li>Tell us about the advantage and merits</li>
          <li>associate the page with the payment system</li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="list2"></ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

In theory, the list should be marked with checkmarks, or rather with images that I uploaded using the "background url", but no icons appear

Comment: Have you tried renaming the image file to for example "test.png"? Is the image available?

Comment: please verify: 1. the path of the image (slash and backslash) 2. the space in the name of the image  (after the \ ). Still the same?

Comment: i tried to rename image to "green.png", it doesn't help, image still can't be loaded

Comment: yes, the path of the image is right, and as I understand it, backslash is used to specify the path to a file with a Russian name. By the way, the space was added by VScode itself, I don't think there is an error in this path

Comment: Pseudo elements are inline by default, so width and height simply don't _apply_. You need to set `display: inline-block` or block or something, or position the element absolute/fixed.

Comment: I tried setting "inline-block" and "position: absolute" but it still didn't work. Perhaps you should take a look at the full CSS code?

Comment: _"and as I understand it, backslash is used to specify the path to a file with a Russian name"_ - no, that is not a thing. If anything, I think the backslash simply "masked" the space character here. But you should really rather use properly URL-encoded URLs to begin with.

Comment: Have you checked whether this actually causes any request that _tries_ to load an image? (Browser dev tools, network panel.)

Comment: Yes, when I wrote the url('/img/image.png') chrome wrote that the file could not be loaded, and then I put two dots in the path "('../img...')" and then there was no more error, but the picture did not appear on the page either

Comment: Returning to the backslash, it no longer matters, because I renamed the file to Latin

Answer (score -1):

There may be a few potential issues with your code that prevent the background images from appearing. Here are some suggestions to fix this.

1. File path: Ensure that the file path to the background image is correct. Double-check that the path `'../img/Без\ названия.png'` is pointing to the correct location and that the image file exists at that path.
2. Special characters in the file name: The file name `'Без\ названия.png'` contains special characters and spaces. Make sure that the file name is correctly encoded in the URL. Instead of using backslashes to escape the space, you can use `%20`. For example, `'Без%20названия.png'`.
3. Image visibility: Check if the image is actually visible by setting a background color for the `:before` pseudo-element. Add `background-color: red;` to your CSS rule and see if a red box appears instead of the image. This can help determine if the issue is with the image itself or its visibility.
4. CSS selector specificity: Verify that the CSS selector you are using to target the `:before` pseudo-element is specific enough to apply the background image. If there are other CSS rules overriding or conflicting with this selector, the background image may not be displayed. You can try adding a higher specificity to the selector, such as `.list1 li:before`, or using the `!important` declaration.
5. Check for errors: Ensure that there are no errors in your CSS file. If there are any syntax errors or missing closing brackets in your CSS, it could prevent the styles from being applied correctly.

By reviewing and addressing these potential issues, you should be able to determine why the background images are not showing up in your list.

Answer (score -2):

.list1{list-style: url('img/Без/названия.png');}

Or

Change backslash to '/' after img/Без

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).